# How to configure Vitest and Styled Components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components, vite, storybook, vitest

I have react project which created with vite and it use typescript.
The project use storybook as well and styled componenets when I run test with vitest I am getting the following error

```
 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'borderRadius')
  src/stories/atoms/button/Button.styles.tsx:8:31
         border-radius: ${props => props.rounded?
                 '50%' :
                 props.theme.spacing.borderRadius.medium + 'px'};
```

in jest we could use jest-styled-components package but I don't how i could solve this with vitest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long search I found that if i use shallow from enzyme it works fine

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import type { ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme'
```

this my test file and it works fine

```
describe('Button', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper
    const mockedOnSubmit = vi.fn()


beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<Button label="Primary" variant="primary" onClick={mockedOnSubmit} size="medium"/>)
})

test('should render with correct props', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toBeDefined()
    expect(wrapper.name()).toBe('styled.button')

    expect(wrapper.text()).toBe('Primary  ')
    expect(wrapper.prop('variant')).toBe('primary')
    expect(wrapper.prop('size')).toBe('medium')
})

test('should invoke onClick prop by clicking on the button', () => {
    wrapper.simulate('click')
    expect(mockedOnSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled()
})

test('should match snapshot', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})

});
```